# use vfs in wso2 esb?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I create a proxy service that transform file new text document.txt from `///d:test/orginal`
to `///d:test/pass` in local

My proxy code is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="testVFS"
   transports="https,http,local"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="https://127.0.0.1:9443/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
  </endpoint>
 </target>
 <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
 <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
 <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///D:/test/Orginal/</parameter>
 <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///D:/test/Pass/</parameter>
 <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///D:/test/Failures/</parameter>
 <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
 <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
 <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
 <description/>
</proxy>
```

But I have an error and not transform files:

```
<TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="SOAP envelope error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out</TryitProxyError>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your proxy your transports are set as:

```
transports="https,http,local"
```

Changing this to

```
transports="vfs"
```

will ensure it tries to use the VFSTransportListener.

Just make sure that the following line is not commented in %ESB_HOME%\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml:

```
<transportReceiver class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener" name="vfs"/>
```

Comment: tanks for your answer , i create vfs

Answer (score 0):

You must use vfs transport. To understand how to use refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/VFS+Transport and http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838852

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the SoapAction endpoint.

Example using:

```xml
<header name="Action" value="urn:mediate"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint key="SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
    </send>
```